# Qt on android how to get positioning with android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, qt, positioning

I'm using Qt (6.4.1) for android. I used to ask "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission to get GPS position using code like:

```cpp
auto permissionGPS = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION").result();
if(permissionGPS == QtAndroidPrivate::Authorized){
   source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(0);
   if (source) {
      auto last = source->lastKnownPosition(false);
      if(last.isValid()){
         receivePosition(last);
      }else{
         connect(source, &QGeoPositionInfoSource::positionUpdated, this, &Locator::receivePosition);
         source->startUpdates();
      }
   }
}else{
   emit GPSRefusal(false);
}
```

Unfortunately if the user perfers to allow "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", this code doesn't work  anymore.

If I replace requested permission with "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" (which is reasonable for my app), I get the following error:

```
W qt.positioning.android: : Position data not available due to missing permission 4
```

Does any one know how to get ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION positioning working with Qt ?

Comment: What is Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps it's a 13 Android version

Answer (score 0):

For an Android 13 device you first have to request COARSE location permission.

And only after you obtained permission request gps FINE permission.

Two steps.

Comment: My issue then, is when user keep coarse location. I found no way to handle it with Qt.
QGeoPositionInfoSource features don't seems to work with it.